# Integrating flash player in JavaFX web browser

Tags: java, adobe, javafx, flash

I created a web browser using WebView and WebEngine classes of JavaFX. It is working fine but not able to play videos. It is opening youtube.com but is not playing videos of youtube. It is asking to install Adobe flash player. Even after installing, the problem is same. Do I have to integrate some plug-in of Adobe Flash Player in my Java code. If yes, how? Or there is some other solution. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebView in JavaFX 2.2 does not support plugin based content such as Flash content.

As alternatives, for launching YouTube video content from JavaFX you can use:

1. [HostServices.showDocument](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/HostServices.html#showDocument%28java.lang.String%29) go launch flash content in the default system web browser OR
2. YouTube's [iframe embedding API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) in WebView rather than it's flash interface.

The YouTube iframe embedding API embeds html5 video content, rather than flash video content and [html5 video content works in WebView](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1437374).

For more info, see http://www.youtube.com/html5

Comment: no.1 using HostService,... how can we implement that? for instance my situation here is if the webpage containing an iframe of that loaded flash...? @jewelsea....