# How to run flash file (.swf) in javafx

Tags: flash, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

in my application, I have to run flash file (.swf) to show some videos. But I dont know how to run flash file in javafx.

Comment: This tutorial will help you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/index.html

Comment: Have a look and here http://www.coderanch.com/t/623708/JavaFX/java/Run-flash-file-swf-javafx

Comment: Why cant you play the same videos just by using JavaFX? It supports FLV & MP4 formats, just like the SWF would have played anywaya - unless we are talking RTMP video?

Comment: how about if we have an iframe containing like jwplayer (flash) @NwDx wouldn't be succeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry if I have to disappoint you but JavaFX cannot run flash files.

Comment: ok sir, would you please tell me which media file are supported by javafx?? (video files)

Comment: Have a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/overview.htm But you could have googled that yourself.

Comment: but i heard there's a solution for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277265/integrating-flash-player-in-javafx-web-browser

Comment: @gumuruh The proposals made there are either not to use flash at all or use it in an external browser. I wouldn't consider that a solution to run flash inside JavaFX.